# CanvasJs React - Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

Tags: reactjs, canvasjs

I want to use CanvasJs React for the first time and follow guide at this [link](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/react/).

The link show three steps :

1. Create a React App
2. Save CanvasJS React Files in your app (downloaded from [link](https://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/))
3. Import CanvasJS React Component

I already done the three steps above, but after finishing the last steps i got this error on the webpage:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Module.<anonymous>
src/assets/js/canvasjs.react.js:42
  39 |  }   
  40 | }
  41 | 
> 42 | module.exports = {
  43 |     CanvasJSChart: CanvasJSChart,
  44 |     CanvasJS: CanvasJS
  45 | };
```

canvasjs.react.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var CanvasJS = require('./canvasjs.min');

class CanvasJSChart extends React.Component {
    static _cjsContainerId = 0
    constructor(props) {        
        super(props);       
        this.options = props.options ? props.options : {};      
        this.containerProps = props.containerProps ? props.containerProps : {width: "100%", position: "relative"};
        this.containerProps.height = props.containerProps && props.containerProps.height ? props.containerProps.height : this.options.height ? this.options.height + "px" : "400px";
        this.chartContainerId = "canvasjs-react-chart-container-" + CanvasJSChart._cjsContainerId++;
    }   
    componentDidMount() {
        //Create Chart and Render
        this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(this.chartContainerId, this.options);
        this.chart.render();

        if(this.props.onRef)
            this.props.onRef(this.chart);
    }   
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        //Check if Chart-options has changed and determine if component has to be updated
        return !(nextProps.options === this.options);
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        //Update Chart Options & Render
        this.chart.options = this.props.options;
        this.chart.render();
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        //Destroy chart and remove reference
        this.chart.destroy();
        if(this.props.onRef)
            this.props.onRef(undefined);
    }       
    render() {      
        //return React.createElement('div', { id: this.chartContainerId, style: this.containerProps });     
        return <div id = {this.chartContainerId} style = {this.containerProps}/>        
    }   
}

module.exports = {
    CanvasJSChart: CanvasJSChart,
    CanvasJS: CanvasJS
};
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var CanvasJSReact = require('./assets/js/canvasjs.react');
var CanvasJS = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJS;
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const options = {
            title: {
                text: 'Basic Column Chart in React',
            },
            data: [
                {
                    type: 'column',
                    dataPoints: [
                        { label: 'Apple', y: 10 },
                        { label: 'Orange', y: 15 },
                        { label: 'Banana', y: 25 },
                        { label: 'Mango', y: 30 },
                        { label: 'Grape', y: 28 },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <CanvasJSChart
                    options={options}
                    /* onRef = {ref => this.chart = ref} */
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm using create-react-app v1.5.2 with:

```
react: 16.6.3,
react-dom: 16.6.3,
react-scripts: 2.1.1

nodejs: v8.13.0
npx: v6.4.1
```

Anyone has ever had a problem like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to the breaking changes in Webpack that was introduced in v2.2.0-rc.5. Here is the [Updated Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjXjbVg9y1ADtyKS_eiLcjbOJRCLYKM5) ([Link 2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am6ZJqYg9Zmfgg5S4zQB2dlauz67)) of [Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElCjaW8ycU-qia974rtSUagwoYWmb5yV/) that you have shared.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hello, It is still not working. Can you please double check? Thank you.

Comment: @Guti, It seems to be working fine. Download the latest version from [official website](https://canvasjs.com/). FYI: If you are using from npmjs, that's not the official one. If you still have issue,a sample project would help us understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, I got it to work by switching the end syntax of the canvasjs.react.js to:

```
export {CanvasJSChart, CanvasJS};
```

And in App.js importing canvas:

```
import CanvasJSReact from './canvasjs.react';
import { CanvasJS } from './canvasjs.react';
import { CanvasJSChart} from './canvasjs.react';
```

Rather than using require. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, when you've done the switching, you don't need this anymore `import CanvasJSReact from './canvasjs.react';`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039), you can't mix `import` and `module.exports`. Try using only `require()` statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I'm already use `require()` statements for `CanvasJSReact` and tried to change `import React, { Component } from 'react';` to `var React = require('react');` but still get the same error output.

Comment: Have you replaced everywhere in the app you used `import`?

Comment: Yes, i created this in the new project with create-react-app that generates just 2 default files that contain `import` statements (App.js and index.js). I have replaced all `import` statements with `require ()` statements in 2 files but still get the same error output.

Comment: But are you still using `export default`? Rule of thumb: `import` goes with `export`, `require()` goes with `module`.

Comment: I tried change `export` to `module.exports` in `App.js` like `canvasjs.react.js` file, but again still got the same error. I really confused about this.

Comment: Okay. Try using `import` / `export`, and avoiding `require()` and `module.exports`.

Comment: I tried using `import` and `export` but got a new error `TypeError: CanvasJS.Chart is not a constructor`. I already upload my file via this [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElCjaW8ycU-qia974rtSUagwoYWmb5yV/view?usp=sharing) and i hope you can help me to fix the file.